# Out of Gas, waiting 3 month

Tags: ether

I have sent 10 ether from my ethereum wallet to my poloniex ethereum wallet, but it doesn't came. Please help me! Im waiting too long! Polo didn't answer, ether didn't came back to my ether wallet! If somebody help me
, I will send some reward to you!

TxHash:
0x2dff536aafdb64512cdacb8cc3a97b2fd53334e156d8c2935c0e5936c7b72d1c

From:
0x7ed1e469fcb3ee19c0366d829e291451be638e59

To:
Contract 0x10555c9e4638bdd01e18fa02bfceacda627e4245

[image]

Comment: The Transaction failed, meaning that the 10 Ether are still with Polinex. If they do not show that in your Polinex wallet, contact Polinex, only they can solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your transaction and it shows cancelled 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2dff536aafdb64512cdacb8cc3a97b2fd53334e156d8c2935c0e5936c7b72d1c

That means it was never deducted from your sending wallet.

The sending wallet https://etherscan.io/address/0x7ed1e469fcb3ee19c0366d829e291451be638e59 has good lot of ETH in it, what wallet did you send it from.  Do you really have $211,273.06 (@ $466.20/ETH) in your wallet right now.

Could you have sent it from an exchange wallet.

To explicitly answer your question, your ETH never left the sending wallet that is confirmed on the blockchain.

Who ever controlled your sending wallet still has your 10 eth that is undisputed based on the blockchain data from the links you provided.  Any donation is welcomed at 0xa3a887abfdcfd5b72ac21fb5f292544cc1d1a4aa thanks.